# call Dialogbox with an action (react Native)(web interface)

Tags: react-native, dialog

react Native:

I have a component to run a Dialogbox. If I call it like follows it works:

{runWelcomeDialog(true)}

I try to call it with a button (the call action of the button works too, i.E. if I run an alert. My code is like:

```
const [dialogVisible, setDialogVisible] = useState(false);

const startDialog = () => {
    setDialogVisible(true)
};


return(...

    <CustomButton
        innerText= "signInTEST"
        customButtonStyle={{ width: "100%" }}
        action= {() => startDialog()}
    />
                
    {runWelcomeDialog(dialogVisible)}

    ...);
```

I tried various versions of it, but to give a clue I tried the with default value "true" then it works too:

```
   const [dialogVisible, setDialogVisible] = useState(true);

   const startDialog = () => {setDialogVisible(true)};


   return(some code

   <CustomButton
       innerText= "signInTEST"
       customButtonStyle={{ width: "100%" }}
       action= {() => startDialog()}
    />

    {runWelcomeDialog(dialogVisible)}
```